# Python 3, print list with scientific notations

Tags: python, list, formatting

I just got started with python, and need help on a school assignment.

The assignment is: 
Below is a list of the SI prefixes from 1e18 to 1e-18 (with step size 3). Print a table with the prefixes and the corresponding power.

prefixes = ['exa','peta','tera','giga','mega','kilo',' ',\
            'milli','micro','nano','pico','femto','atto']

I know how to print two tables next to each other using the zip-function, but I'm having trouble printing out a table with scientific notations. 
I've been trying to create a table like this:

table = range(1e-18, 1e18, 1e-3)

And then I get: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as integer.

I've tried formatting it, but I must be doing something wrong. I've also tried writing the list manually, 
table = [1e-18, 1e-15, 1e-12, 1e-9, 1e-6, 1e-3, 0, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12, 1e15], but when I print it it becomes decimals. 
I've tried formatting with:

["{:.e}".format(i[table]) for i in table]

This only gives me the TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm new to this, so please try putting it as simple as possible. 
Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to store them as strings then type cast when you want them as integers

Comment: You don't actually need floating point numbers 1e-18, 1e-15 etc. You just need integers -18, -15, etc and then format the output from them.

Comment: `["{:.0e}".format(i) for i in table]`